# set_field_upload in grocery crud not rendering

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-3, grocery-crud

i am trying to use set_field_upload to upload a images in a database field called "photo", the crud is working perfectly for text/dates...etc

But u can't use the file upload

- it's not showing as a file button, its only a text input.
- no errors in console or network.
- the field type is text, i tried varchar type as well with no luck.

Here is the code

```
try {
    $crud = new grocery_CRUD();

    $crud->set_table('test');

    $crud->set_field_upload('photo', 'assets/uploads/files');

    $output = $this->grocery_crud->render();
    $this->_example_output($output);

    } catch(Exception $e) {
        show_error($e->getMessage().' --- '.$e->getTraceAsString());
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by changing the version, i tried 1.5.8 and 1.5.0.

I got it working by using 1.5.5